# copy all method names - Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ editing question:
 If am editing a java file, is there way to copy all method names and arguments into clipboard?

Some thing like this...

```
java.lang.String.length():int
java.lang.String.charAt(int):char
java.lang.String.codePointAt(int):int
java.lang.String.codePointBefore(int):int
java.lang.String.codePointCount(int, int):int
java.lang.String.offsetByCodePoints(int, int):int
```

Copying from 'Structure' does copy all(or selected) method names.. but that does not include classname.

Comment: Also for me it doesn't copy the parameters :/, did you find a way around it?

Comment: That was not needed in my case. Please ask as a question, there may be a way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know how to do it with InteliJ but I can suggest you to use `javap` - utility that is included into your jdk. Just run it from command line and specify the class name. It prints "prototype" of java class; something like `.h` file in c.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's possible to configure External Tool in IDEA to run javap for the current class and then copy method names from the console in IDEA.

Comment: I managed to configure it using the following IDEA Macros in the Add External Tool popup:

Program: javap
Arguments: $FileClass$
Working directory: $OutputPath$

Answer (score 25):

If you are interested in just names of the methods

1. Go to structure view
2. Select all
3. Right click to copy

Comment: And notice that this is a horrible, awful, no-good "feature".  I want everything that's in the structure pane, and the fact that it leaves out all the good parts is maddening.  Copy should mean copy, not "copy some of the stuff, but leave out lots of the most useful parts."

Comment: It only copied the method name, and it doesn't include the parameter :(

Comment: Worked well to create my test class comments, thank you.